What is the linguistic perspective on stylistic change over time?
I teach Language Change at A level in the UK.  We were recently discussing what the linguists perspective was on stylistic change - the reason why a written mode text from the 1920s (or even 1980s) is so obviously not contemporary, despite following similar grammar rules.  We thought that semantic change and lexical change partly explain it.  We also considered informalisation and ideological change.  Is there a theory or concept that deals with language change as essentially driven by fashion or stylistic preference?

Linguists are still arguing about exactly how language develops in the first place (is the mind a complete "blank slate", or does it have hardwired components ready to be "initialized" with locale-specific words and syntactic rules?). So I doubt they have any well-recognized patterns for how languages change over time. Imho language is like biological evolution itself - there's no identifiable "direction" or "pattern" - languages and organisms just shift towards whatever works best, which essentially changes randomly over time (fashion?). But this is a Q for SO Linguistics, not ELU

There are definitely changes in literary style driven by fashion - compare the prolix Victorian sentence with the more modern simpler style. But this seems a too open-ended topic. I guess some people have theorized about this sort of thing, e.g. Marxist critics relating literary style to the economic system. But insofar as it's about literary style, it probably belongs on Literature SE (linguists don't care as much). And of course things like education and technology affect style (printing, telegraph, SMS typed on a numeric keypad, etc.) But some is just random/reaction to other random things.

A question like this needs to take more account of all the possible reasons for changes, some of which can be deliberate, but others can be societal.  Most obviously, until comparatively recently, the formal language can be said to have been 'policed' by authors of dictionaries, like Dr Johnson, and of grammars and by school masters/tutors and dominated by people of a certain social origin.  Even the availability of extended reading and writing was limited by social class, cost and technology.  Most of what was written was addressed to people of that class.  Now, we all read, write and publish

Methinks I oughta text my boy Willy for their perspective.
